# Apache cxf java-first and SOAP module npm

Tags: java, node.js, web-services, maven, soap

I have deployed a cxf-jaxws-javafirst maven project with its default method: HelloWorld.sayHi(String text).

http://localhost:8080/prueba/HelloWorld?wsdl
[image]

On the other hand, I have a soap client implemented on Nodejs with soap module.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
//soap module
var soap = require('soap');
//url of the wsdl
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/prueba/HelloWorld?wsdl';
//variable
var args = {arg0: 'friend'};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
      client.sayHi(args, function(err, result) {
          res.send(result);
      });
    });
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

})
```

I have try to send soap message to other WebService, e.g. http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl and my client code works, so I think I have some error in my WebService.

In my maven project I have just added this line of code just above the declaration of the interface for debugging messages into and out of my web service :

```
@org.apache.cxf.feature.Features(features = "org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature")
```

In this way I got the input message(soap client) and output message(WebService response):

Input Message:

```
mar 05, 2015 1:33:08 PM org.apache.cxf.services.HelloWorldImplService.HelloWorldImplPort.HelloWorld
INFORMACIÓN: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 17
Address: http://localhost:8080/prueba/HelloWorld
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8], accept-charset=[utf-8], accept-encoding=[none], connection=[close], Content-Length=[230], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], host=[localhost:8080], SOAPAction=[""], user-agent=[node-soap/0.8.0]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:tns="http://prueba.prueba/"><soap:Body><sayHi><arg0>Hola</arg0></sayHi></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Output Message:

```
mar 05, 2015 1:33:08 PM org.apache.cxf.services.HelloWorldImplService.HelloWorldImplPort.HelloWorld
INFORMACIÓN: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 17
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Unexpected wrapper element sayHi found.   Expected {http://prueba.prueba/}sayHi.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

And Java error:

```
mar 05, 2015 1:33:08 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
ADVERTENCIA: Interceptor for {http://prueba.prueba/}HelloWorldImplService#{http://prueba.prueba/}sayHi has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected wrapper element sayHi found.   Expected {http://prueba.prueba/}sayHi.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Whit SoapUI, I achieve send the string:
This is the InputMessage (Client: SoapUI).

```
ID: 18
Address: http://localhost:8080/prueba/HelloWorld
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate], connection=[Keep-Alive],
Content-Length=[285], content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], host=[localhost:8080],
SOAPAction=[""], user-agent=[Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)]}
Payload: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pru="http://prueba.prueba/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pru:sayHi>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>"?"</arg0>
      </pru:sayHi>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I do not know I'm doing wrong, I hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to remove the namespace `pru` from SoapUI and I have got the same error so this is my error, I have to get add the namespace. `Pru` refers to namespace `tns` of my wsdl.

I read the issues of github of node-soap  and one refers to the namespace `tns`. 
https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/537

I have changed these line of wsdl.js file:

```
this.ignoredNamespaces= [ 'tns', 'targetNamespace', 'typedNamespace']
WSDL.prototype._ignoredSchemaNamespaces = ['tns', 'xs', 'xsd'];
```

by

```
this.ignoredNamespaces= [  'targetNamespace', 'typedNamespace']
WSDL.prototype._ignoredSchemaNamespaces = ['xs', 'xsd'];
```

and my code works.

Thank you herom

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the maintainers/collaborators over at [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

I don't know `cxf-jaxws-javafirst` but looking at your image of the `wsdl` I can't find the `pru:` prefix defined anywhere, so I don't know where SoapUI is assuming that the `<sayHI>` element should have this prefix attached...

To me the produced SOAP Body of `node-soap`:

```
<soap:Body>
  <sayHi>
    <arg0>
      Hola
    </arg0>
  </sayHi>
</soap:Body>
```

seems valid, based on the input `wsdl`.

Comment: I have tried to remove the namespace "pru" from SoapUI and I have got the same error so this is my error. I have to get add the namespace. "Pru" refers to namespace "tns" of my wsdl.